# Is there any way to create android:text state selector for button?

Tags: android, xml, button, selector

A **beginner** here.

**We create state selector for `android:background` and `android:color` etc so why can't we create it for `android:text`?**

I have a button and I want to change the text when I press button using selector, is it possible?

**Button text in Normal state--> hello**

**Button text in Pressed state--> Hey**

Here is my button and the drawable selector, please tell me how to create selector for `android:text`

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:background="@drawable/selector_xml_name"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="126dp"
     android:text="Hello" />
```

Following is button_effect.xml file in drawable directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

Thank you so much for your support...

Comment: I don't think it is supported by Android. You can *simulate it* using different pre-drawn backgrounds having required text, or use `OnTouchListener` to do it programmatically

Comment: ummm Ok sir thank your for your comment, But why its not supported any strong reason?

Comment: As I see it - because nobody thought it would be required

Comment: ok got it, thank you... :-)